# python automatic statistical linear regression

Tags: python, regression

Is there some python packages that helps to do statistical linear regression? For example, I hope such program could do something like automatically performing different types of statistical tests (t-test, F-test etc.) and then automatically removes redundant variable etc., correct for heteroskedasticity etc.. Or is LASSO just the best?

Comment: Scikit-learn and scipy should be good places to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform and visualize linear regression in Python with a wide array of packages like:
[scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html), [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/index.html) and [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html). LASSO is available through statsmodels as described [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html). When it comes to automated approches to linear regresssion analysis you could start with [Forward Selection with statsmodels](https://planspace.org/20150423-forward_selection_with_statsmodels/) that was described in an answer in the post [Stepwise Regression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433372/stepwise-regression-in-python/29835822#29835822).